# How to access an attribut of a class defined inside an other class?

Tags: python, class

Is it possible in Python to access an attribute of class B defined in a class A from the class A ?
For example, access 'a' from the method 'toto'.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
    def toto(self):
        ...
    class B(object):
        def __init__(self, a):
            self.a = a
```

Thank you for yours answers.

Comment: Can you make your example complete, please? Currently it's unclear what exactly you are trying to access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @timgeb I want to be able to use in class A instances created inside class B. In my previous example,  I was wondering if it's possible to use instance a of class B in the method toto of class A.

Answer (score 1):

You can. The class B is bound to the instance of class A.
But you can only access class variables of B. To access instance variable of B you have to create an instance of B and attach it to the object of A.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = A.B(100)

    def toto(self):
        print(self.b.a) # this will print 100

    class B(object):
        def __init__(self, a):
            self.a = a
```